# Assembler: adding and printing two words whose sum is larger than a word

Tags: assembly, printing, x86, addition

I have issues in assembler language: how to add byte and word and print out the result. For example FFFF+FF. The result would be 100FE. The problem is that I dont know how to print out the whole result since it is bigger than one word. I can print only 00FE, where is the 1?

Example (b1 is a byte, w1 is a word):

```
mov ah, 00h
mov al, b1
mov bx, w2
add ax, bx
```

Comment: What architecture?  Do you have any 32-bit registers?

Comment: The `1` is in your carry bit. You'll need to extend your value to two words and move the carry into the high-order word, low order byte. Then you'll have to figure out how to print a two-word result, making sure you get the bytes in the right order!

Comment: Do a jump-on-no-carry `jnc` skipping the printing of `1`. And then print the word.

Answer (score -1):

Been an extremely long time for assembly, but you will likely need to use the carry flag (more detail here: [check if carry flag is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139772/check-if-carry-flag-is-set))