# Using condition flags as GNU C inline asm outputs

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm working on some code where it would be highly desirable to take condition-flags output from an inline asm block and use that as a condition to branch on in the calling C code. I don't want to *store* the flags (that would be useless and inefficient; there are already more efficient ways to achieve the result) but use the flags directly. Is there any way to achieve this with GNU C inline asm constraints? I'm interested in approaches that would work for multiple instruction set architectures, with the intent of using it with the condition flags produced by the architecture's LL/SC style atomics. Of course another obvious usage case (separate from what I'm doing) would be to allow the outer C code to branch on the result of the carry flag from an operation in inline asm.

Comment: You might find [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2015-05/msg00006.html) discussion interesting, if not currently helpful.  And let me make another plug for intrinsics.  While it may seem like inline asm provides good solutions, the code *around* your inline stuff can pay a performance penalty that costs more than whatever benefit you get from the asm.  Just saying.

Comment: There is certainly something to be said for intrinsics, but the devil is in the details. On some targets they produce very bad code. On ARM they produce a `dmb sy` barrier (synchronize with all external hardware on the bus) rather than the desired `dmb ish` (synchronize only with cpu cores). And on others they produce library calls instead of inline code, or produce code that's incompatible with some newer targets when using an older `-march` rather than allowing the runtime branches with multiple variants we need for such targets.

Comment: Thankfully modern compilers are **very good** about integrating inline asm and C as long as the constraints are written well. Right now I have the whole lls/sc sequence inside an asm block, which requires separate asm per atomic operation per target. If I could refactor to separate asm blocks for the "ll" and "sc" parts, with C code for the operation in between, I'd have identical efficiency without any of the per-target duplication; all ll/sc-type targets could use the same C code with only the ll and sc arm varying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with GCC6 on x86 you can actually use `"=@ccCOND"` as output (where `COND` is any valid x86 condition code).

Example [originally from here](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/02/25/new-asm-flags-feature-for-x86-in-gcc-6/), cleaned up by David's suggestions:

```
int variable_test_bit(long n, volatile const unsigned long *addr)
{
    int oldbit;
    asm volatile("bt %[value],%[bit]"
                 : "=@ccc" (oldbit)
                 : [value] "m" (*addr), [bit] "Jr" (n));
    return oldbit;
}
```

Before using this, you should test if `__GCC_ASM_FLAG_OUTPUTS__` is defined.

[Documentation at https://gcc.gnu.org](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#FlagOutputOperands).

Comment: I'm not sure `I` is the right constraint here.  Longs can be 64bits on some platforms and I is only for values 0..31.  I'm also not clear why we need to cast away the `const` and `volatile`.  It's an input param, so const shouldn't be a problem.  It's a `m` so volatile is implicit.  I might also be tempted to add symbolic names (`[bit]` and `[value]`).  Doesn't affect functionality, but might be clearer for those of us used to intel format.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I admittedly did not manage to have gcc produce an `adc` instruction, when adding `oldbit` with two other integers ...

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to do adc.  Anyway, that wasn't the OP's requirement.  He wanted jumps.  Your code does that (https://godbolt.org/g/gA2qgL).

Comment: If you only want to allow 0..63, you should ask for `*addr` in a register.  The memory-operand form of `bt` is much slower, especially with a register source ([10 uops on Haswell vs. 1 for reg,reg](http://agner.org/optimize/)).  Also, a register source would allow accessing memory other than the qword your operand tells gcc about, so you'd really want [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956379/att-asm-inline-c-problem/47358313?noredirect=1#comment81680441_47358313): `[value] "m" (*(const unsigned long (*)[]) addr)` to tell gcc it might access anywhere relative to `addr`.

Comment: TL:DR: `bt*` instructions with a memory operand have insane-CISC bitstring semantics: http://felixcloutier.com/x86/BT.html, and this is handled with microcode for register sources.  Best to make the compiler load into a register.

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial solution, but I don't really like it because it requires putting the branch instruction inside the asm, and because it requires a very ugly GCC feature that other "GNU C compatible" compilers might not support: `asm goto`. It does however allow the branch outside the asm to be eliminated. The idea is:

```
static inline int foo(...)
{
    __asm__ goto ( " .... ; cond_jmp %l[ret0]" : : "r"(...) ... 
                   : "clobbers" : ret0 );
    return 1;
ret0:
    return 0;
}
```

When inlined into the caller that does `if (foo(...)) ... else ...`, the conditional jump in the asm block ends up pointing directly to the `else` branch, even though at the abstract-machine level there are return values involved.

Comment: The Linux kernel uses this kind of construct in several places, and apparently it does optimize as well as you'd hope when you do `if( foo(...) ) {} else {}`.  The compiler never actually puts a `1` or `0` in a register, just uses the `asm goto` as the `if` branch.  You are forcing the choice of which side is take vs. fall-through, though.  Probably gcc6 condition-code outputs will optimize at least as well, unless your code has an early-out condition (so the conditional branch isn't the last instruction in your asm statement).  In that case, this is still useful, +1.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately GCC doesn't support accessing condition flags outside of asm statements. If you don't want to set a value then you'll have to move the conditional branch into the asm statement. That means either using [asm goto labels](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#GotoLabels) that you've already discovered, or also bringing branch target into your asm statement.

You might also want to check to see if either GCC's old style [__sync atomic builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html) or the newer [memory model based atomics](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) provide the functionality you want out of the atomic instructions you're using.