# Intel x86 Assembly - Reading and copying the carry flag

Tags: assembly, x86, flags, carryflag, eflags

I am currently creating a program to convert an decimal into binary. I am currently using the shifting method in order to get the 0's and 1's.

I have looked at other threads which leads to using LAHF and PUSHF to access the flags and set it; however, all I want to do is get the current value of the carry flag and store it into a register (i.e: 1's or 0's at that current position) which will later be copied into the array. Since I am not too familiar with LAHF or PUSHF, I was wondering if you can complete the same task I asked above using LAHF or PUSHF.

For example, I want to move the current CF into eax: **mov edx,cf** (I know this doesn't work, but I am looking for something like this). After I have copied either the 1 or 0, I will then move it into the array which was passed from a C++ program.

Comment: Integers are already binary. By "convert an integer into binary" do you mean convert a binary integer into a base-2 ASCII representation?

Comment: Use `setc` instruction. e.g., `setc dl`

Comment: @RossRidge Sorry, I meant decimal value into binary. (Base 10 to base 2 representation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the most obvious way to store the carry in EDX is:

```
setc  dl
movzx edx, dl
```

It is shorter (6 bytes) than the methods proposed in the other answers but the shortest (5 bytes) has to be:

```
pushfd
pop   edx
and   edx, 1
```

Comment: shorter: `xor edx,edx / ` generate flags `/ setc dl`.  5 bytes with good performance (choice of `xor` before or `movzx` after [depends on microarchitecture](http://agner.org/optimize/).  Shortest: `sbb edx, edx` 2 bytes, also quite good performance.  Or `sbb edx, edx  / neg edx` 4 bytes, if you really need 0/1 rather than 0/-1.  `sbb reg,reg` is actually used by gcc in some cases.  (seen in the disassembly of `/bin/ls` for example.)  I'm out of votes or I'd def upvote this.  The other answers are mostly insane.

Comment: @PeterCordes Your first example __looses__  the carry flag through `XOR`

Comment: Oh right.  Of course you have to put the xor before the flag-generating instructions, I should have said that.  Fixed inside the edit window :)

Comment: If you can't avoid `movzx`, prefer a different register, e.g. `setc cl` / `movzx eax, cl` to allow [mov-elimination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all) on the `movzx`.  The `setcc` will have a false dependency so pick a register that was already part of the dependency chain leading to it, or is definitely cold.  Or better, with the upcoming APX extension, `setc rax`.  ([Why XOR before SETcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68034464))

Answer (score 4):

Almost identical to this question:
[check if carry flag is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139772/check-if-carry-flag-is-set)

You could uses JC, JNC to branch based on carry flag then mov 1 or 0 into the register you want to use.

Or use ADC command.

```
mov eax, 0
adc eax, 0
```

I will add that PUSHF then pop into the register and mask out the bit you want with an XOR would also work.  The ADC approach is probably best

Comment: Thank you! This worked flawlessly on my assembly program.

Comment: @guest What mask what you use to single out the carry bit through using a `XOR` instruction as stated in your last paragraph?

Comment: `mov eax,0` / `setc al` is the same code-size, although `adc eax,0` is probably at least as good on all CPUs if you can't xor-zero a register *before* setting FLAGS.  On P6-family, `setc al` and then reading the full register would have a partial-register stall if you haven't xor-zeroed, which is worse than the 2 uop cost of `adc`.  And [on early Sandybridge-family](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51664369), `adc reg, 0` is special-cased as a single uop because the immediate is zero.  (And most other CPUs including Broadwell and later have single-uop `adc` all the time.)

Answer (score 1):

Just do a conditional assignment based on carry:

```
mov eax, 1
jc carry_set ; If carry is indeed set, skip the next line
mov eax, 0
carry_set:
```

In general, carry is typically used for conditional jumps, not as a value. See if the larger code can be reformulated this way.

EDIT: modern Intel CPUs also have a conditional move command:

```
mov eax, 0
cmovc eax, 1 ; assign if carry is set
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! If only I can select two answers! Both of these seems to work fine as I just tested both and ended with the same results.

Comment: `setc al / movzx eax, al` would be *much* better than either of those.  `setcc` has existed since 386.

Comment: Update: prefer `movzx` from a different register, e.g. `setc cl` / `movzx eax, cl` to allow [mov-elimination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all) on the `movzx`.  The `setcc` will have a false dependency so pick a register that was already part of the dependency chain leading to it, or is definitely cold.  Or better, with the upcoming APX extension, `setc rax`.  ([Why XOR before SETcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68034464))

Answer (score 1):

You can always try subtract with borrow. For example ...

```
SBB EAX, EAX
```

If the carry flag is set, EAX will be 0xFFFFFFFF. If it is clear, the result will be 0x00000000.